# Borre huayra.list y ahora me aparece este mensaje "El indice de sofware esta dañado" cuando intento instalar algo no se como revertirlo

Tags: sudo

Estaba siguiendo un tutorial para instalar wine y en una parte decía que tenía que borrar huayra.list y después de hacerlo deje de hacer el tutorial y cuando intento descargar algo me aparece un texto que dice
"El índice de software esta dañado"
este es un importante fallo en su sistema de gestión de software.
Busque paquetes rotos con sypnatic, revise los permisos del archivo y que el formato de <</etc/Apt/sources.list>> sea el correcto. Actualice la información de software con <> y <<sudo apt-get install -f>>